# prevent form default behavior in Vue.js

Tags: forms, vuejs2

I'm building a Vue.js app with a form and I was wondering is there a way to prevent the HTML 5 forms default behavior using Vue.js built in `.prevent`? I have tried `<form.prevent>`  and `<form v-on:submit.prevent>` but to no avail. Any help here would be great?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`v-on`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) directive (shorthand `@`) is to bind a Vue instance *method* or a JS expression to an event:

> Attaches an event listener to the element. […] The expression can be a method name, an inline statement, or omitted if there are modifiers present.

Therefore even if you do not specify a method or an expression / inline statement, your `.prevent` modifier should work in any case:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    formSubmit() {
      console.log('form submitted');
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form @submit.prevent>
    <span>Form WITH submit.prevent and no expression attached</span>
    <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
  </form>
  <form @submit.prevent="formSubmit">
    <span>Form WITH submit.prevent</span>
    <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
  </form>
  <form @submit="formSubmit">
    <span>Normal form without prevent</span>
    <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
  </form>
</div>
```